# How to send find -exec to output file with {}

Tags: sed, find

I am trying to find and replace text inside several .sas files using find -exec along with sed, but I would like to direct the output to new .sas files named according to the result of the find command (if that makes sense to anyone). Something like this:

`find . -type f -name "*.sas" -exec sed 's/2020/2021/g' {} > {}_new \;`

I'm new to Unix, and I've googled this question but couldn't find anything that specifically addressed the issue of naming the new output .sas file using the find command result of {} as a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -name "*.sas" -exec sed -i'_new' 's/2020/2021/g' {} \;
```

Comment: @Freddy that was required a simple edit I did, now it answer the question